# Golang using migrate with dockertest

Tags: postgresql, go, testing, migrate

The goal is to test logic on database. It seems that [dockertest](https://github.com/ory/dockertest) might be useful for it and they provide [examples](https://github.com/ory/dockertest/tree/v3/examples) for how to setup the test. However, these ephemeral databases are empty (no migration done).

How to migrate database when using dockertest?

Comment: How are you handling database migrations currently?

Comment: @DanielFarrell golang-migrate as a CLI in docker-compose. But I've seen that it can be also used as a lib and there's some suggestions to use it inside test setup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure that's the best approach but I've connected a few examples and came up with a full migration via [golang-migrate] lib on test setup.

Below the `TestMain` is setup func that sets Dockertest with postgres DB connection. Just before `m.Run()`, that runs tests, there's `runMigrations` which uses golang-migrate to pull all scripts in local dir and apply them to db. It works but it's rather slow.

```
func TestMain(m *testing.M) {
    // uses a sensible default on windows (tcp/http) and linux/osx (socket)
    pool, err := dockertest.NewPool("")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Could not connect to docker: %s", err)
    }

    // pulls an image, creates a container based on it and runs it
    resource, err := pool.RunWithOptions(&dockertest.RunOptions{
        Repository: "postgres",
        Tag:        "11",
        Env: []string{
            "POSTGRES_PASSWORD=secret",
            "POSTGRES_USER=user_name",
            "POSTGRES_DB=dbname",
            "listen_addresses = '*'",
        },
    }, func(config *docker.HostConfig) {
        // set AutoRemove to true so that stopped container goes away by itself
        config.AutoRemove = true
        config.RestartPolicy = docker.RestartPolicy{Name: "no"}
    })
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Could not start resource: %s", err)
    }

    hostAndPort := resource.GetHostPort("5432/tcp")
    databaseUrl := fmt.Sprintf("postgres://user_name:secret@%s/dbname?sslmode=disable", hostAndPort)

    log.Println("Connecting to database on url: ", databaseUrl)

    resource.Expire(120) // Tell docker to hard kill the container in 120 seconds

    // exponential backoff-retry, because the application in the container might not be ready to accept connections yet
    pool.MaxWait = 120 * time.Second
    if err = pool.Retry(func() error {
        db, err = sql.Open("postgres", databaseUrl)
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }
        return db.Ping()
    }); err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Could not connect to docker: %s", err)
    }

    // Migrating DB
    if err := runMigrations("../migrations", db); err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Could not migrate db: %s", err)
    }

    //Run tests
    code := m.Run()

    // You can't defer this because os.Exit doesn't care for defer
    if err := pool.Purge(resource); err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Could not purge resource: %s", err)
    }

    os.Exit(code)
}

func runMigrations(migrationsPath string, db *sql.DB) error {
    if migrationsPath == "" {
        return errors.New("missing migrations path")
    }
    driver, err := postgres.WithInstance(db, &postgres.Config{})
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    m, err := migrate.NewWithDatabaseInstance("file://"+migrationsPath, "postgres", driver)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    err = m.Up()
    if err != nil && err != migrate.ErrNoChange {
        return err
    }
    return nil
}
```